# Having an issue with my contact us page and submitting a request

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, forms, contact-us

[image]

I keep getting these errors when submitting a request via my contact us page. Can anyone help? I have a webform extension.

[image]

Comment: Seems like ajax called but 500 error, so check ajax controller called or not.

Comment: Can you explain how I would be able to do this?

Comment: check which url called into network panel

Comment: Yeah there's a 500 error, check my original post. Any ideas on how to fix that error?

Comment: can you disable ajax submit into module and check it, is that working

Comment: That's done on Magento admin?

Comment: yes maybe, or form wise, you need to check that module document

Comment: I have another form that is working not sure why this one is stuck on sending... By the way the form sends it just gets stuck on sending...

Comment: You have using 3rd party modules  for contactus page?

Comment: Yeah Vladamirwebforms extension but both my forms are using the same extension and only this one is not working properly.